# lexer error while using ng-attr-href

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in results" class="text-center">
                <td style="font-size:12px" layout="row" layout-align="center">
                    <a ng-attr-href="{{d.status == 'DONE' ?
                             'https://{{d.url}}' : undefined}}">
                    {{d.date}}
                    </a>
                </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to check if the value of "status" is "DONE". If the value is "DONE" url will be applied as link to the date value else the date(r.date) is not a url link.

I am getting error while running the code "lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use the interp symbols within themselves, use regular concatenation:

```
<a ng-attr-href="{{d.status == 'DONE' ? 'https://' + d.url : undefined}}">
```